# SIGINT handling differences between bash 3 and 4

Tags: bash, shell-script, signals

I have a script which works great in bash 4.3, but gives me unexpected behavior with bash 3.2. Here's a simplified version:

```
set -o errexit -o pipefail

task() {
    local name=${1}
    local duration=${2}
    trap 'echo "[${SECONDS} secs] ${name}: SIGINT"; exit 255' INT
    echo "[${SECONDS} secs] ${name}: Running"
    sleep "${duration}"
    echo "[${SECONDS} secs] ${name}: Done"
}

trap 'echo "[${SECONDS} secs] SIGINT"; exit 255' INT
task 'Task 1' 5 &
task 'Task 2' 5 &
wait
echo "[${SECONDS} secs] Done"
```

Here's the output when run with bash 4.3 (4.3.42(1)-release) after CTRL-C'ing two seconds into it:

```
[0 secs] Task 1: Running
[0 secs] Task 2: Running
^C[2 secs] SIGINT
[2 secs] Task 2: SIGINT
[2 secs] Task 1: SIGINT
prompt>
```

Same thing but with bash 3.2 (3.2.57(1)-release):

```
[0 secs] Task 1: Running
[0 secs] Task 2: Running
^C[2 secs] SIGINT
prompt> [5 secs] Task 2: Done
[5 secs] Task 1: Done
```

Are there known issues preventing the above script from working correctly under bash 3.2? Do workarounds exist?

Here are a few things I've tried:

- No signal handler in the parent:

  ```
  # bash 4.3
  [0 secs] Task 1: Running
  [0 secs] Task 2: Running
  ^C[2 secs] Task 2: SIGINT
  [2 secs] Task 1: SIGINT
  prompt>

  # bash 3.2
  [0 secs] Task 1: Running
  [0 secs] Task 2: Running
  ^C
  prompt> [5 secs] Task 2: Done
  [5 secs] Task 1: Done
  ```
- No signal handlers at all:

  ```
  # bash 4.3
  [0 secs] Task 1: Running
  [0 secs] Task 2: Running
  ^C
  prompt>

  # bash 3.2
  [0 secs] Task 1: Running
  [0 secs] Task 2: Running
  ^C
  prompt> [5 secs] Task 2: Done
  [5 secs] Task 1: Done
  ```
- Signal handler in parent that kills the process group with SIGINT (`kill -INT -- -$$`):

  ```
  [0 secs] Task 1: Running
  [0 secs] Task 2: Running
  ^C[2 secs] SIGINT
  [2 secs] Task 2: SIGINT
  [2 secs] Task 1: SIGINT
  prompt>

  [0 secs] Task 1: Running
  [0 secs] Task 2: Running
  ^C[2 secs] SIGINT
  prompt> [5 secs] Task 2: Done
  [5 secs] Task 1: Done
  ```
- Signal handler in parent that kill the process group with SIGTERM (tasks trap SIGTERM):

  ```
  # bash 4.3
  [0 secs] Task 1: Running
  [0 secs] Task 2: Running
  ^C[2 secs] SIGINT
  [2]    92813 terminated  bash minimal_example.sh
  prompt>

  # bash 3.2
  [0 secs] Task 1: Running
  [0 secs] Task 2: Running
  ^C[2 secs] SIGINT
  Terminated: 15
  Terminated: 15
  [2 secs] Task 2: SIGTERM
  [2 secs] Task 1: SIGTERM
  [1]    92836 terminated  /bin/bash minimal_example.sh
  prompt>
  ```

The last is the closest to working properly in 3.2, *but* that same code behaves differently in 4.3.

Answer (score 2):

It may be that you are a victim of a well known `bash` problem that frequently hits `make` users.

I did not yet check bash 4, but `bash 3` incorrectly does jobcontrol inside scripts. This usually causes makefiles that contain a loop over several subdirectories not to be easily killable by `^C` because the sub processes run in separate process groups even though these commands are not interactive commands.

`smake` includes a workaround for `/bin/sh` being `bash` and explicitely forwards SIGINT to the procress group of the currently running command. But this is software written in `C`.

The same cannot be implemented with usual shells in scripts as there is no standard UNIX command to retrieve the process group of a child.

Comment: This may be a different (related?) issue - when I kill the process group with SIGTERM, all of the children are killed as well. This makes me think they're all running in the same process group.

Comment: To be completely sure, I just verified that all of the spawned processes are indeed in the same process group as the parent.

Comment: Are they in the same process group as the shell that runs the script and as the tty?

Comment: They're in the same process group as the shell that runs the script, but not in the same group with the interactive shell.

Comment: It may be that bash 3 ignores SIGINT in shell scripts and continues with the execution. This would be non-conformant behavior. You can verify this by installing a trap for SIGINT that just calls `exit.`

Comment: When I have a `trap exit INT` in task(), every process is killed immediately in bash 4.3. In 3.2, the script exits to the prompt immediately, but the tasks run to completion in the background.

Comment: Now I understand your "problem". Commands that are run in the background are not subject to signals from the terminal. The bash3 behavior is correct and this is what you get as well from `ksh88` and `ksh93`.

Comment: So is the bash 4 behavior incorrect?

Comment: This is my interpretation.